# How can I force Log4net from failing silently so that I might implement the FailoverAppender?

Tags: customization, log4net, failover, appender

Log4j has an appender called the FailoverAppender.  This appender allows you to choose a primary appender and as many secondary appenders as you'd like. If the primary appender fails to log, the secondary kicks in and logs.  I noticed that Log4Net does not have this type of appender.  I know that Log4Net can log in parallel, but I'd much rather have a secondary appender activated and log only if the primary appender fails.  What's preventing me from accomplishing this is that Log4Net is a fail-stop logging system.  **Is there a way to force an exception to be thrown from an appender when logging fails so that I can implement a FailoverAppender?**  I'm thinking I need to override some public ErrorHandler which implements IErrorHandler.  I've been trying to tailor the ForwardingAppender to do what I want, but since each attached appender fails silently, I can't get things to work.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.   **If there are examples out there, please point me to them.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after reading stuartd's answer, I did a bit more research on implementing IErrorHandler.  During that research, I stumbled across the [FallbackAppender](https://code.google.com/p/log4netcontrib/).  I feel a bit foolish now that I've found this.  I just thought I'd put this answer out there so others can find the FallbackAppender a lot quicker.  Thanks peer and stuartd.  I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own custom failover appender from a SkeletonAppender. If logging fails, remove your current appender and add your backup appender like:

```
class FailoverAppender : AppenderSkeleton {

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
        try {
            //Add the appender implementation
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            try{
                //Remove the current appender and add an other, then append the message to the new appender
                var root = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
                var attachable = root as IAppenderAttachable;
                attachable.RemoveAppender(this);

                AppenderOnError appender = new AppenderOnError(); //Your backup appender
                attachable.AddAppender(appender);
                appender.Append(loggingEvent);

            }
            catch (Exception e2){
                ErrorHandler.Error("An error occurred while connecting to the logging service.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But appenders don't throw exceptions, so how would the failover appender know to use the backup appender?

Comment: An appender can throw an exception, log4net just ignores it as if nothing happened. A generic way would be the ErrorHandler, the problem with appenders is that they can fail silently, like log4net is designed or not flush immediately (fail later). Only implementing your own appender can ensure that if the appender is called you get the desired behavior.

Comment: Ah, so the code in "//Add the appender implementation" would throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [example from the log4net mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200409.mbox/%3CDDEB64C8619AC64DBC074208B046611C0C77D9@kronos.neoworks.co.uk%3E) of how to implement IErrorHandler:

> log4net uses a plugin framework for error handling, each Appender has
>   an ErrorHandler property which holds an [IErrorHandler](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.IErrorHandler.html) object. This is
>   used to handle errors reported by the Appender. The default error
>   handler used is the [OnlyOnceErrorHandler](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4net/tags/1.2.13/src/Util/OnlyOnceErrorHandler.cs) and this writes the first
>   error only (per appender) to the console.
>
> If you want to handle errors in a custom way all you need to do is to
>   create your own implementation of the IErrorHandler interface and then
>   set the ErrorHandler property on the appenders to use this new type,
>   for example:

```
<appender ...>
     ...
     <errorHandler type="MyErrorHandler, MyAssembly"/>
</appender>
```

> Error handlers can only be set on appenders and there is no way of
>   globally overriding the default error handler for all appenders.

Your error handler then can perform the failover logging.